# woocommerce show price to registered user only

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show the price to registered users only. I wrote a separate plugin as my code will be removed on update.

Below is the code, it's working but the problem is that it does not show text with a hyperlink.

I see only "Registered Users are able to view pricing".
no href to account page.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html','members_only_price');

function members_only_price($price) {    
    if(is_user_logged_in()){
        return $price;
    }    
    else {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
        return 'Only <a href="' .get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('myaccount')). '">Registered Users</a> are able to view pricing.';
    }    
}
```

Comment: Same code working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if it'll work or not. But looking at your code I noticed you didn't put a space between the "." on your return.

try this

```
function members_only_price($price){
    if(is_user_logged_in()) {
        return $price;
    } 
    else {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
        return 'Only <a href="' . get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('myaccount')) . '">Registered Users</a> are able to view pricing.';
    }
}
```

*note: not tested.*

Answer (score 0):

The get_permalink() function returns the URI for your post but you need to actually echo that URI by opening php tags inside the HTML.

Try this

```
    return 'Only <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('myaccount')) ; ?>">Registered Users</a> are able to view pricing.';
```

Comment: Thats a wrong answer, the whole function is within <?php ?> not in HTML.

Comment: My apologies to all who read my incorrect answer. I'm a php newb who's found this site helpful and wanted to start contributing. @robin vinzenz, thanks for pointing out my error. I made the mistake of not testing my answer before submitting. Won't make that one again...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test the code in my answer, but i would rather say that you shouldn't use `woocommerce_get_page_id` since it is [deprecated](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-woocommerce_get_page_id.html).

Instead use the function `wc_get_page_id` [reference to docs](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_page_id.html).

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html','members_only_price');

function members_only_price($price) {    
    if(is_user_logged_in()){
        return $price;
    }    
    else {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );

        return 'Only <a href="'.get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ). '">Registered Users</a> are able to view pricing.';
    }        
}
```

Or try another [Example](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/display-my-account-link-in-a-template-file/) in woocommerce docs.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html','members_only_price');

function members_only_price($price) {    
    if(is_user_logged_in()){
        return $price;
    }    
    else {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );

        return 'Only <a href="'.get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ). '">Registered Users</a> are able to view pricing.';
    }        
}
```

Please tell if that worked for you, good luck.